# Error can't show when click form input

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript:

```
<script>
function updatecode() {
    var widthError = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>Error</span>";
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    if(width < 300) {
        document.getElementById('error_width').innerHTML = widthError;
    }else {
        document.getElementById('error_width').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="auto" onchange="updatecode()" />
<span id="error_width"></span>
```

When I enter width = 400, it is ok. And when I enter width = 200, it does not show the error message. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why

Let's first take a look at the code:

```
else {
    document.getElementById('error_width').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

This will happen if it is bigger than 400 right? And when it goes down to 200, its `visibility` is still hidden. That's why it doesn't show up.

### Fixing it

Make it visible will fix it.

```
if(width < 300){
    document.getElementById('error_width').innerHTML = widthError;
    document.getElementById('error_width').style.visibility = "";
}else{
    document.getElementById('error_width').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('error_width').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

and actually you don't need to hide it because it doesn't have anything it it when the `width` is bigger than `300`.

### And...

You might want to change this

```
var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
```

to this:

```
var width = parseInt(document.getElementById('width').value,10);
```

---

Hope this help you out.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/yW8wt/